# How to split or gather zip parts like 7zip with objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, unzip

I'd like to be able to gather all zip parts someone would send to me splitted file with 7 zip http://www.linglom.com/2008/10/12/how-to-split-a-large-file-using-7-zip/

What algorithm does 7zip use ? What methods to do the same programmatically in objective c (suppose I already use a zip library I now need to split a file or unite multiple parts of a file)

Comment: Use "libzip", it's C so you can use it in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks but as I said above I am interested in splitting the zip not by zipping itself : does libzip really support splitted zip ?